# Adding Text to Existing Data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way in Excel to add text without spaces to the ending text of contents of a column.  For example:  I have 600 records and I want to add the letters OP directly after the contents of all records in column A.

Answer (score 1):

Select the top row in another column and enter:

```
=A1&"OP"
```

Copy this down to all rows. If you than want this in column `A` as values, copy the new column and past in column A as past special, values.

The `&` symbol combines text strings. It can have a cell reference, a formula, or a string itself surrounded with `"`.